# Multiple bouncing balls triggered by MouseListener

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener

I want to do a bouncing balls application in java. Each ball should take place by mouse clicking and each of them should have random speed, color, radius and starting position. I managed to do everything except the part where mouse listener takes place. Whatever i do in the mousePressed method didn't work. What should i do to make user create a random ball when he presses the mouse?

**EDIT:** This is the last version of my code. Now the problem is that i can't create more than one ball. When i click on the screen same ball is just keeps speeding.

*BouncingBalls Class*

```
public class BouncingBalls extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

private Ball ball;
protected List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>(20);
private Container container;
private DrawCanvas canvas;
private int canvasWidth;
private int canvasHeight;
public static final int UPDATE_RATE = 30;

int x = random(480);
int y = random(480);
int speedX = random(30);
int speedY = random(30);
int radius = random(20);
int red = random(255);
int green = random(255);
int blue = random(255);
int count = 0;

public static int random(int maxRange) {
    return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
}

public BouncingBalls(int width, int height){

    canvasWidth = width;
    canvasHeight = height;

    ball = new Ball(x, y, speedX, speedY, radius, red, green, blue);
    container = new Container();

    canvas = new DrawCanvas();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.addMouseListener(this);

}

public void start(){

    Thread t = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

            while(true){

                update();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / UPDATE_RATE);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

public void update(){

    ball.move(container);
}

class DrawCanvas extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        container.draw(g);
        ball.draw(g);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){

        return(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Bouncing Balls");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setContentPane(new BouncingBalls(500, 500));
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    balls.add(new Ball(x, y, speedX, speedY, radius, red, green, blue));
    start();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

*Ball Class*

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ball{

public static int random(int maxRange) {
    return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
}

private BouncingBalls balls;
int x = random(480);
int y = random(480);
int speedX = random(30);
int speedY = random(30);
int radius = random(20);
int red = random(255);
int green = random(255);
int blue = random(255);
int i = 0;

public Ball(int x, int y, int speedX, int speedY, int radius, int red, int green, int blue){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
}

public void draw(Graphics g){

    for(Ball ball : balls){

        g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
        g.fillOval((int)(x - radius), (int)(y - radius), (int)(2 * radius), (int)(2 * radius));
    }
}

public void move(Container container){

    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;

    if(x - radius < 0){

        speedX = -speedX;
        x = radius;
    }
    else if(x + radius > 500){

        speedX = -speedX;
        x = 500 - radius;
    }

    if(y - radius < 0){

        speedY = -speedY;
        y = radius;
    }
    else if(y + radius > 500){

        speedY = -speedY;
        y = 500 - radius;
    }
}
}
```

*Container Class*

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Container {

private static final int HEIGHT = 500;
private static final int WIDTH = 500;
private static final Color COLOR = Color.WHITE;

public void draw(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(COLOR);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
 }
```

**ERROR:** I get "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" error in this part of code:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){

    for(Ball ball : balls){

        g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
        g.fillOval((int)(x - radius), (int)(y - radius), (int)(2 * radius), (int)(2 * radius));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't worked. addMouseListener(this); should be working right? But it doesn't.

Comment: What are you adding the `MouseListener` to?

Comment: For the movement problem: try adding print statements inside the move method to see the real values of x and y at the end of it, or if you now how to use a debugger, add a breakpoint in the method and see if it's working as intended. About the mouse listener: it doesn't seem like you added the mouse listener to your `BouncingBalls` instance as other people suggested. Even if it's not working, post it on the code so we can see the whole thing.

Comment: Oh, you forgot to start your thread. That's probably the problem for the movement issue.

Comment: Yes, i figured that out and sorry for late updating. My only problem now is that i can't create multiple balls. When i click on the screen same ball is just keeps speeding instead of creating a new ball. I will update my code in a minute.

Comment: The loop should be on your `DrawCanvas` class. I'll update my answer to post some example code there.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to render more than one ball, you should create another class to contain all the properties needed to draw a ball (maybe even a `draw (Graphics g)` method to delegate the drawing). Then you would have a list of balls on your `BouncingBalls` class which should be iterated over and painted on the `paintComponent` method.

Said that, your `mouseClicked` handler would just create a new `Ball` instance and add it to the list.

**EDIT:**
Example of how the drawing process would be on your `DrawCanvas` class:

```
class DrawCanvas {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        container.draw(g);

        for (Ball ball : balls)
            //the draw method should only care of the specific ball instance 
            //you are calling it from
            ball.draw(g);
    }
...
```

I think you are having problems separating your problem into classes and making their instances cooperate to do what you want. If you are indeed having doubts about this, I recommend you read some articles/books about the topic to get a better idea of the concepts of a class and an object and how they work; it'll definitely help you do your programming with ease.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. -1

Comment: @Doorknob I'm assuming that he is having a logical problem while you are assuming he's having a technical problem. My answer is as valid as yours in my opinion :)

Comment: actually that makes sense. :P removed -1

Comment: Do i have to make a list? I created a class named Ball(extends BouncingBalls) and make a draw method in it but i can't call that method.

Comment: @Miral the Ball class shouldn't extend `BouncingBalls`, it should be another class that will help you keep each ball individualized. The list I mentioned would contain all the balls on your application, and you `paintComponent` method should iterate and draw all of them. You can either put the logic to draw in the `paintComponent`method or abstract it on a `draw` method on the `Ball`. Anyway, you should update your main post with the things you have tried out so we can have a better look at your attemps so we can help you out!

Comment: i did as you said. But now when i click on the screen just one ball appears and it doesnt moving. I'm getting hopeless about this program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the MouseListener to the component:

```
public BouncingBalls() {
  this.addMouseListener(this); // <-- Add this object as a MouseListener.
  this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code in your `main` method:

```
frame.addMouseListener(this);
```

You need to add the mouse listener to the frame/panel.

(response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573369/multiple-bouncing-balls-triggered-by-mouselistener/14573417#comment20337713_14573369) comment by you) Alternatively, if you want to add the listener to the panel, first you must call

```
setFocusable(true);
requestFocusInWindow();
```

In your `BouncingBalls` constructor. Then you can add the mouse listener to the panel with:

```
addMouseListener(this);
```

This is because the panel does not initially have focus.

The easiest way to do it, though, is to just add the mouse listener to the frame.

Comment: A component doesn't need to be focusable to receive mouse events, only key events ;) - In fact, a mouse click will make the window active and the component (if it's capable of it) focused anyway....Also, the mouse listener should be added to the `BouncingBalls` panel and not the frame, simply because if you add it to the frame, it could be consumed by other components and you need to react to the mouse click within the context of the panel and not the frame.